# Using different 'Forms' for different methods

Tags: python, google-app-engine, jinja2

I hope i can express myself right, here it goes.

I have a handler for a html page that has the objective of editing a "chapter". In this page the chapters are listed and you can use a button to add more chapters. So the first time you open the page, the chapters are listed and a button to add more. If you click 'add', it should present you the same page but with a form for the chapter information.

My problem is passing the information of what chapters are we editing when we reload the page, because a can't pass the 'tut_key' - the reference to the chapters.

editTut.html:

```
{% for chap in chaps %}
       Title: {{ chap.title}}<br>
    {% endfor %}

{% if not editMode or editMode == 0 %}
<form ????????>
    <input id="tutBtnNext" type="submit" value="Add">
</form>
{% endif %}

{% if editMode == 1 %}
    <form method="post">
        <!-- form stuff -->
    </form>
{% endif %}
```

the class:

```
class EditTut(FuHandler):
    def get(self):
        tutID = self.request.get('tut_key')
        tut = db.Key.from_path('Tutorial', tutID)
        chaps = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Chapter " +
                            "WHERE tutorial = :1", tut)
        self.render('editTut.html', chaps=chaps)

    def post(self):
        tutID = self.request.get("tut_key")
        tutorial = db.Key.from_path('Tutorial', tutID)
        title = self.request.get("chapTitle")
        content = self.request.get("content")
        note = self.request.get("note")

        chap = Chapter(tutorial=tutorial, title=title,
                       content=content, note=note)
        chap.put()
        self.redirect('/editTut?tut_key=%s' % tutID)

    #should i use something like this? 
    #I tried but i can't find a way to call this function on the html
    def addChap(self):
        tutID = self.request.get("tut_key")
        self.redirect('/editTut?tut_key=%s' % tutID)
```

Comment: Let me make sure I understand. The issue is remembering what chapter you were already editing when someone reloads the page? If that's correct, then using a cookie would probably be a good way to go.

Comment: i completely forgot about cookies... i'm going to try that thanks

Comment: Cool, I've added it as an answer, in case that helps anyone else out in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting a cookie would likely be a good option here. When they select a chapter you could send a cookie that specifies that option. Then, each time the page is loaded you just check for that cookie. If the cookie exists and is valid, you should know what chapter they are editing.

You can set cookies in Google App engine like this:

```
self.response.set_cookie('name', 'value', expires=expire_time, path='/', domain='example.com')
```

`value` could be something that references the chapter you're working with. If you leave `expires` blank, it should expire when they close the browser (which you may want).

You can get the cookie with:

```
self.request.cookies.get('name','')
```

Then you could just assign that cookie to a variable, and check it for the chapter info.

Answer (score 1):

I hope I understand you correctly, I had to load forms based on criteria and did it like so:

```
    if not editMode:
            params = {} 
            form = 'add_mode.html'
    else:
            params = {"data", data}
            form = 'edit_mode.html'

    return self.render_template(form, **params)
```

Comment: but i don't want to use another html page. As Nate said i probably need to use cookies

Comment: np glad you found a solution